# How to approach to business mails when the sender starts becoming a bit informal?

Tags: writing-style, formality, business-language, email, letter-writing

I am sharing emails repeatedly with a woman who is sharing a prospect for a job with me.

It started with "Dear Candidate"
Then

"Dear (my name)"

On the other hand, each time I have been replying to her with "Dear Madame" salutation.

Should I also start changing my salutation as well? If yes, then to what?

Comment: If you are the hiring manager, you can address her however you please, within the bounds of decency. If you are the candidate, then address her as Ms./Dr. [surname].

Comment: (By first name, informal),: 'Dear Pluto,'  , (by title and surname, more formal): 'Dear Ms Hopkins,' ,  'Dear Sir, Dear Sir or Madam, 'Dear Madam' (especially to somebody whose name is not known) etc. can be used as per the context.  'Also' and 'as well' in the sentence,  "Should I also start changing my salutation as well?:, is an example of  redundancy.

Comment: @mahmudkoya Got it! May Allah bless you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If she is referring to *you* as **Candidate**, it sounds like you are the one looking for the job, correct? (Just wasn't entirely sure from your post.) If so, I would take my cue from her. So as long as she's now referring to *you* by name, I would feel free to do the same in return with her.

You don't indicate whether she's addressing you with your first name or as **Mr. So-and-so**, but either way, I would stick with **Ms. So-and-so** in return, and avoid using her first name unless she directly says something like, "*Ms. So-and-so is my mother's name. Please call me Barbara*," (or whatever it might be).

Good luck. Hope you get it!

Comment: She was addressing me by my first name, "Hello (my first name)".

Comment: Yeah, as mentioned above, I'd still stick with her last name--just to be safe--unless she _insists_ otherwise. Wishing you success!